# html 5 input validation polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, validation, user-input

Ways to simulate html 5 input validation in browsers that don't support it (while still supporting native implementations), ie the `required`, `pattern` etc attributes. 
Just so you don't freak out I'll still will be using server side validation :P

Comment: http://html5please.com/#polyfill search for form validation

Comment: There are also others, http://ericleads.com/h5validate/ you can use modernzr to fill in missing features https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Here's a good article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/HTML_forms_in_legacy_browsers